# Cell TableView and holds

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm Beginners developer and I have a question, I will be very grateful for the response :)

I have a "cell" which is located in the tableView, how to create one so that if the user holds a finger at that location for 2 seconds then the caller.

Comment: You can use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

add the gesture to the cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *twoSecPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePress:)];
[twoSecPress setMinimumPressDuration:2];
[cell addGestureRecognizer: twoSecPress];
```

handle your method:

```
-(void) handlePress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
 if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UITableViewCell *cellView=(UITableViewCell *)recognizer.view;
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```